# Taking input from inside handlebar .hbs file

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have code inside a `.hbs` file like this

```
{{ # each content }}

.....

 <input name = "a" type="text" id="a_id" /> 
 <button onclick="my_fn(a)"> BUTTON </button>
{{/each}}
```

Inside the code I have defined a button clicking which I want to call

another function:

```
function my_fn(a){
   alert("Hi"+ a);
}
```

where `"a"` is the user input. This way I'm unable to send argument to `"my_fn"`. How this can be done.